Local linearization of general Fokker-Planck equation with spurious drift?
The most general Fokker-Planck equation for a probability density $f$ over $2d$-dimensional phase space is $\partial_t f = Lf$ for the differential operator
$$L f = -\partial_i(u_i f) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_i \partial_j (D_{ij} f)$$
where the the drift vector $u$ and the diffusion matrix $D$ are functions on phase space, $\partial_i:= \partial/\partial \alpha_i$ denotes a partial derivative in the $i$th direction in phase space, and the repeated indices $i,j=1,\ldots,2d$ are summed over.   $D$ must be positive semidefinite. The Fokker-Planck equation can equivalently be written
$$L f = -\partial_i(v_i f) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_i (D^{ij} \partial_j f)$$
where $v$ and $u$ differ by the spurious drift $u_i-v_i=\partial_j D_{ij}/2$.
Importantly, $L$ is Gaussian preserving — mapping Gaussian distributions to Gaussian distributions — if and only if (a) the drift vector $u$ is linear in phase space, $u_i (\alpha) = u_i(0) + w_{ij}\alpha_j$, and (b) the diffusion matrix $D$ is constant. Because condition (b) means $u=v$, condition (a) can equivalently be taken to be the requirement that $v$ is linear. (This is sometimes called a "linear Fokker-Planck" equation, although this is potentially confusing. All Fokker-Planck equations are linear in $f$. "Linear" here refers to the corresponding Langevin equation.)
Now suppose $L$ is not Gaussian-preserving, but I want to approximate it by a Gaussian-preserving operator $L^{(\beta)}$, which is accurate in the neighborhood around a particular point $\beta$ in phase space, by performing some sort of a Taylor series expansion. I think this is generally called "local linearization". What is the canonical way to do this?
In the case where $L$ already has a constant diffusion matrix $D$, it's pretty clear that one should simply replace $u$ by its linear Taylor approximation, $u_i^{(\beta)}(\beta+\Delta\beta) := u_i (\beta) + \Delta\beta_j \partial_j u_i(\beta)$, so $$L^{(\beta)}f := -\partial_i(u_i^{(\beta)} f) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_i \partial_j (D_{ij} f).$$  In this case of constant $D$, it's equivalent to use the second form of $L$ and linearize $v$ because $u=v$.
However, if $D$ is not constant in phase space, it's not clear what to do.  We can replace $D$ in $L$ with $D(\beta)$, but the spurious drift $u-v$ is non-zero so the two approaches (linearizing $u$ vs linearizing $v = u+\partial D/2$) give different choices of locally linearized dynamics $L^{(\beta)}$.  Which, if either, is the canonical way to locally linearize $L$? And what properties does this choice have that make it special?
(References greatly appreciated. I've looked through the standard stuff like Risken without any luck.)

Since Gaussian processes are completely characterized by two moments, I would try to compute the first moments of your non-Gaussian process and then use them to define a Gaussian process (hoping that it will properly characterize fluctuations around $\beta$).
In one dimension the idea would be the following. Let the Fokker-Planck equation for the non-Gaussian process be
$$\partial_t\rho_t (x)= -\partial_x \left(A(x)\rho_t(x)\right)+\partial^2_x \left(B(x)\rho_t(x)\right).$$
Compute or estimate the mean and variance,
$$ \mu(t) = \int dx\,x\,\rho_t(x), \quad \sigma^2(t)=\int dx\,\left[x^2-\mu^2(t)\right]\,\rho_t(x).$$
Then use them to define a Gaussian process, like a sort of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck with time-depending coefficients.
This procedure is sometimes used to describe stationary fluctuations around meta-stable states (i.e. points that are local maxima of the stationary distribution). See, for example, this paper: Ross, J. V., Taimre, T., & Pollett, P. K. (2006).
But, to be honest, I don't think that the idea of approximating the generator by a local linearization makes sense in arbitrary problems. One problem is that you should also state how this approximation would affect the field at the boundaries. Moreover, the generator could be non-analytical in some points (as the case of x=0 in the geometric Brownian motion), making Taylor expansions in those points unfeasible. I think it would be easier to help if we discussed a concrete example in which we can see what makes you think that the propagator is approximately Gaussian around some $\beta$ (i.e. stating the dynamics, initial and boundary conditions).
Lastly, locally in space and time, any process is approximately Gaussian, see Wikipedia: Euler-Maruyama method.

Thanks for the thoughtful reply. The application we have in mind is proving a general $\hbar\to 0$ limit of the Lindblad equation in quantum mechanics; we are specifically trying to be as general as possible. I think the problem in the case of no boundary and C^k functions is already quite interesting and broadly applicable, and indeed I would characterize non-C^2 functions as unphysical exceptions.
